# Php doc: typing a string class name which will always implement a given interface

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a function which returns a class name (string), but the returned class always implements the same interface:

```
<?php

interface BaseInterface {}
class SomeClass implements BaseInterface {}
class AnotherClass implements BaseInterface {}

/**
 * @return ....
 */
function getClassName($someCondition): string
{
    if ($someCondition === 42) {
        return SomeClass::class;
    } else {
        return AnotherClass::class;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to give this information in the `@return` tag? Something like this (imaginary syntax):

```
/** @return BaseInterface::class */
```

The final goal is to make IDEs understand that `getClassName(...)::myInterfaceMethod()` is valid.

### EDIT: a concrete use case of the problem

Here is a runnable example which show how I use `::class` in my actual code.

I reworked the code to be as short as possible, but it is actually part of a Symfony project, running with php 7.4.

The idea is to implement one class per social network; all these little classes implement `SocialNetworkInterface` and only have static methods. They are never instanciated, but they are consulted by calling their static methods.

*Note*: The variables `$user` should be typed as `User`, but in order to shorten the code, I just leave them untyped in the parameters.

The problem explained in my question (IDE is complaining) happens line 79, inside `renderLinkForUserNetwork()`:

```
$class = $networkClass::getFontAwesomeLogoClass();
$url = $networkClass::getUrlForUsername($networkUsername);
```

```
<?php

interface SocialNetworkInterface
{
    public static function getName(): string;
    public static function getBaseUrl(): string;
    public static function getUrlForUsername(string $username): string;
    public static function getFontAwesomeLogoClass(): string;
}

abstract class AbstractSocialNetwork implements SocialNetworkInterface
{
    public static function getUrlForUsername(string $username): string
    {
        // Most social networks use this kind of urls, but of course, this can
        // be overloaded in final classes:
        $baseUrl = static::getBaseUrl();
        return "$baseUrl/$username";
    }

    public static function getFontAwesomeLogoClass(): string
    {
        $name = static::getName();
        return "fab fa-$name";
    }
}

class Facebook extends AbstractSocialNetwork
{
    public static function getName(): string
    {
        return 'facebook';
    }

    public static function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return ('https://www.facebook.com');
    }
}

class Twitter extends AbstractSocialNetwork
{
    public static function getName(): string
    {
        return 'twitter';
    }

    public static function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return ('https://twitter.com');
    }
}

class SocialNetworkHandler
{
    public function getSocialNetworksForUser($user): array {
        // Should return all the social network classes for which the user has
        // information to give (normally depends on the user, fake data is given
        // here for simplicity):
        return [
            Facebook::class,
            Twitter::class,
        ];
    }

    public function renderLinkForUserNetwork($user, string $networkClass): ?string
    {
        // Make it runnable for this example, normally retrieved from $user
        // and $networkClass:
        $networkUsername = 'example';

        // An ugly workaround: of course, $networkClass is not an instance of
        // SocialNetworkInterface, but calling static methods work the same
        // between class name strings and objects:
        /** @var SocialNetworkInterface $networkClass */

        // When not using the ugly workaround just above, the IDE is complaining
        // here (method not found in string):
        $class = $networkClass::getFontAwesomeLogoClass();
        $url = $networkClass::getUrlForUsername($networkUsername);

        return <<< HTML
            <a href="$url"><i class="$class"></i></a>
        HTML;
    }

    public function renderLinksForUser($user): string
    {
        $links = [];
        foreach ($this->getSocialNetworksForUser($user) as $networkClass) {
            $links[] = $this->renderLinkForUserNetwork($user, $networkClass);
        }
        return implode("\n", $links);
    }
}

$handler = new SocialNetworkHandler();
$user = null; // Should be a User entity
echo $handler->renderLinksForUser($user);
```

Output:

```
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/example"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/example"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how it works, unfortunately. You are supposed to specify a return **type** here, and even though BaseInterface::class is dynamic, it would be a return **value** (which is of type `string`).

Comment: Let me clarify: in my question, `/** @return BaseInterface::class */` is an imaginary syntax which would satisfy my needs. The final goal is to make IDEs understand that `getClassName(...)::myInterfaceMethod()` is valid. (Question edited)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But from what I can see, since the function `getClassName()` returns a string, you will be calling `myInterfaceMethod()` on the returned string, and not on the actual class that you want. This is sounding more and more like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info). I think we need to see the actual surrounding code to be able to get further on this one, as I don't think the function `getClassName()` is a viable solution to your problem, but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Ok, question edited